# Docker with Nginx php-fpm does not load images, css or js

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

I'm making an application with Laravel 10. I have the following settings:

Docker:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./infra/docker/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - ./infra/docker/php/dev.ini:/usr/etc/php/conf.d/dev.ini
    working_dir: /app
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - local-bridge
  web:
    image: nginx:1.25
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./infra/docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - app
      - postgres
    networks:
      - local-bridge
  postgres:
      image: postgres:15.2
      restart: unless-stopped
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
      networks:
        - local-bridge
      environment:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
networks:
  local-bridge:
    driver: bridge
```

Nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /app/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass rex-app-1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Standard suggestion from Laravel documentation, just change `$realpath_root` to `$document_root`. I don't know why `$realpath_root` doesn't work.

I added an image to the `/public` directory: `/public/image.jpg`.

When trying to access `http://localhost/image.jpg` I get a 404:

```
Request URL: http://localhost/image.jpg
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

The same happens with css and js files.

API requests for login and CRUDs are 100% functional. What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to access image, css and js files through a reverse proxy with Docker Nginx and php-fpm, but I get 404